# How to get elements from a condition node in a Realtime Database Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get from the Firebase Realtime Database node, not the entire list, but only the one that contains the value "ok".

I can get the whole list using the User model

```
val list:List<User> = it.children.map {it.getValue(User::class.java)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get only the users that have the id property set to "ok", then you should use a Query line in the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val usersRef = rootRef.child("users")
val okQuery = usersRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo("ok")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val user = ds.getValue(User::class.java)
            Log.d("TAG", ds.key + " -> " + user.id)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
okQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
kolya -> ok
sasha -> ok
```